# Where can I find the complete English translation of the Vishnusmriti and Naradasmriti along with commentaries if possible?

Tags: translation-request

I would like to read the Vishnusmriti and Naradasmriti in English along with commentaries online. Can anyone provide me relevant links?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vishnu Smriti without commentary is available here: [THE INSTITUTES OF VISHNU, TRANSLATED BY JULIUS JOLLY](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe07/index.htm).

Narada Smriti without commentary is available here: [Narada Smriti](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe33/index.htm).

Answer (score 5):

- [Narada Smriti](https://archive.org/stream/naradiyadharmasa021669mbp/naradiyadharmasa021669mbp_djvu.txt)
- [Vishnu Smriti](https://reviewout.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/vishnu-smriti.pdf)

Unfortunately commentaries are not available. If I find, i will update my answer.